# Grub Rescue set on partition that doesn't exist

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I recently got a new laptop with Windows 7 installed. I downloaded 12.04 LTS ISO and created a bootable USB stick. I booted into Ubuntu on my laptop and installed Ubuntu, choosing the 'side by side' option for Windows and Ubuntu.

Now when I boot I get this error and a Grub rescue prompt.

```
error: no such device: f0e797ec-17f0-4777-8296-1a44b8524753

ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,msdos5) (hd2,msdos1)
set
prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub
root=hd0,5
```

Notably, a `set` command returns partitions that don't exist when I do an `ls`.

Furthermore, when I do an `ls` on all of the partitions shown above, they all return 'unknown filesystem'. Which I take to mean that none of the partitions are linux partitions.

Any idea what the heck might be going on here?

Comment: Perhaps is it using EFI? (Being a new laptop, I'm sure it is.) Also, don't you get an error message? Just the Grub prompt?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the error message I was getting

Comment: Looks like it is using UEFI. Is that the cause of this? Any idea how I should proceed from here, given I cannot boot into windows or ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the partitions that ubuntu was installed on (sdc2, sdc3) and installed ubuntu onto sda4. Then I set the prefix and root to point to hd0,4. Its working for me now.